# How to get instance of generic object using StructureMap with 2 different cases?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have following interface

```
 public interface IBuilder<T>
 {
    T Create(string param);
 }
```

with many classes that implement the interface above. One of them is:

```
 public class ConcreteABuilder : IBuilder<ConcreteA>
 {
        public ConcreteA Create(string param)
        {
            return new ConcreteA();
        }
 }
```

I'm using StructureMap to register all classes that implement `IBuilder<>`

```
Scan(x =>
{
      x.TheCallingAssembly();
      x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IBuilder<>));
});
```

Now, I have 2 cases

**EDITED**

I get the types(in both cases) in the form of **System.Type**

**Case 1**

At runtime I get any **T** type(**System.Type**) (e.g. **typeof(ConcreteA)**) and I need to get the matched builder instance. In this case it must return **ConcreteABuilder** instance.

**Case 2**

At runtime I get the type(**System.Type**) of some implemented IBuilder(e.g.  **typeof(ConcreteABuilder)**) and I need to get the matched builder instance. In this case it must return **ConcreteABuilder** instance.

How using StructureMap's ObjectFactory to solve Case1 & Case2?

Thank you

Comment: How do you intend to use the ConcreateABuilder, if you do not know the closing generic type at compile time? Are you planning to use reflection to invoke the Create method?

Comment: - somewhat related question, still unanswered is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336897/how-to-get-instance-of-generic-object-using-structuremap-with-2-different-cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is registering your types with:

```
x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IBuilder<>))
```

Then asking the container for an `IBuilder<ConcreteA>` or a `ConcreteABuilder` will return a `ConcreteABuilder`... now the problem is that since you don't know the type until runtime (selected by the user or something?), you can only use the non-generic version:

```
object someBuilder = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(thePassedInTypeAtRuntime);
... then use reflection to invoke the createMethod
```

or

```
dynamic someBuilder = (dynamic)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(thePassedInTypeAtRuntime);
....
```

and somewhere where you actually know that you're asking for a an IBuilder that can return ConcreteA

```
ConcreteA myA = someBuilder.Create(someParams);
```

Comment: I don't know which type I'll get in order to resolve its builder. I receive the types as System.Type. I Updated my post

Comment: Well, you either need to know the type at compile time (somewhere in your calling chain), or use reflection to invoke a method on the Builder... ie you can get the instance fine using ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeHere); but you get a System.Object that you need to cast to some usable type... another possibility is to cast it to dynamic...

Answer (score 2):

Use this in StructureMap configuration

```
x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IBuilder<>))
```

now to resolve generic type at runtime

```
Type openType = typeof(IBuilder<>);//generic open type
var type = openType.MakeGenericType(modelType);//modelType is your runtime type

var builder = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance(type);//should get your ConcreteABuilder
```

Comment: Isn't `builder` just going to be of type `object`? How could we actually cast it to something we could call `Create` on?